# Function to get scroll position and scroll maximum size not working

Tags: javascript

I have the function below that is called from an onscroll event that's assigned to a DIV.

It's not working. I end up getting the following values when the page is at the maximum scroll position:
scrollTop = 55
offsetHeight = 529

When I inspect the DIV that has the onscroll event that triggers the function, I see the following computed value:
206.667px

I noticed that if I resize the browser window, the offsetHeight value changes. But, I've also noticed the value is less than the size of the body tag itself.

I'm confused. How can the top and max values not equal each other when the page is at the bottom of the page? Anyone know what I'm missing?

FYI - I've tried scrollHeight and clientHeight, too; they also seem to be giving inaccurate values, at least based on my expectations.

```
function scrollPos(id){
    var top = document.getElementById(id).scrollTop;
    var max = document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('scrollTest').innerHTML = 'top: '+top+'<br>max: '+max;
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal after you get scrollPosition. Are you trying to determine if the scroll bar is at the bottom of the DIV?

Comment: Hi, Rathish. Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to know, as well as if it's at the very top, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//In order to determine if you are at the top you have to check if scrollTop is equal to 0.

var scrollTop = document.getElementById(id).scrollTop;

if(scrollTop === 0)
{
    console.log("I am at the top");
}

//In order to determine if you are at the bottom you have to check if scrollTop + offsetHeight is greater than scrollHeight

var offsetHeight = document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight;
var scrollHeight = document.getElementById(id).scrollHeight;

if(scrollTop + offsetHeight > scrollHeight)
{
    console.log("I am at the bottom");
}
```

Checkout the working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rathishc24/vrLqon7w/). Please ignore that its written as an AngularJS directive but the concept remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for being able to assist while still being nice about it! I really appreciate it! This solution worked, although for some reason one of my pages required me to add 1 pixel and make it greater than or equal to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A tad too lengthy for a comment, but quoting MDN:

> The `Element.scrollTop` property gets or sets the number of pixels that
>   the content of an element is scrolled upward. An element's scrollTop
>   is a measurement of the distance of an element's top to its topmost
>   visible content.

and

> The `HTMLElement.offsetHeight` read-only property is the height of the
>   element including vertical padding and borders, in pixels, as an
>   integer.

The two convey rather different things, why are you expecting them to be the same?

Comment: I never said I understood everything perfectly, hence asking...apologies. Perhaps telling me which two properties would give me what I want would be a tad more helpful? scrollHeight is also not giving me the right value.

Comment: @flasshy A good start would've been to actually say what you want to do. That was never stated in your question. It's now there in the comments, but without that, how could anyone tell?